# Laravel 4.2 eloquent relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new at laravel and have been using laravel 4.2 in an old server. I have to join three tables to get my required data. The structure is as follows:

Queue Table:

> | id | patient_id | shift_id | date|

Patient Table:

> | id | name | age | gender |

Shift Table:

> | id | time |

I need my controller to return object data with **patient name, shift time and date**. I have three models of each table. How can I obtain this? I have been trying one to meny relations but not been able to complete this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent way

```
class Queue  extends Model
{
   protected $appends = ['patient_name','shift_date'];

   public function patient()
   {
      return $this->blongsTo(Patient::class,'patient_id'.'id');
   } 

   public function shift()
   {
      return $this->blongsTo(Shift::class,'shift_id','id');
   } 

   public function getPatiantNameAttribute()
   {
      return $this->patient->name;
   }

    public function getShiftDateAttribute()
   {
      return $this->shift->time;
   }
}
```

Then

```
$queue = Queue::find(1);  

$queue->patient_name;
$queue->shift_date;
```

This approach uses [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$queue = Queue::with('patient','shift')->find(1);  

$queue->patient->name;
$queue->shift->time;
```

read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: The result returns null in both cases. How can I specify the patient_id column and shift_id column to look for in the queue table?

Comment: @szskdgi You can specify foreign key and local key in second and third parameter

Comment: @szskdgi in the find function `1` is something hardcoded,  do you even have a queue with id 1 ? plz change it man

Comment: yes i do have that. using the parameters, the result returns object with all columns from the tables. I just want patient name as a single variable and not the object

Comment: i want the result like the one Juene Guerrier's answer generates

Comment: you  mean `$queue->patient->name;` returns an patient object !!??

Comment: I want a result with direct `$queue->patient_name` as I am making an api directly from the result

Comment: @szskdgi it's the better and eloquent way, this approach is better because it uses eager loading and you can reuse this relation later, I understand what you say, i will update my answer, then plz accept

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer. I do want to learn it the eloquent way :D

Comment: @szskdgi what I have added is an  accessor, but believe me the first approach was really awesome, professionals do that . plz read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Ok. I will use the first approach. The API has been generated now! Thanks again for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

### Query Builder

```
       $data = DB::table('queue')
        ->join('patient', 'queue.parent_id', '=', 'patient.id')
        ->join('shift', 'queue.shift_id', '=', 'shift.id')
        ->select('patient.name', 'shift.time', 'queue.date')
        ->get();

       dd($data);
```

The documentation explains it more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Comment: Works like a charm but I was looking for a more eloquent way to achieve this. It'll be good for learning purposes too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eloquent you need to have models.
For every database table you can generate models like :

```
php artisan make:model Queue
php artisan make:model Patient
php artisan make:model Shift
```

After that model needs some relationships.Define the relationships like this.

```
class Queue extends Model
{
    /**
     * So now the Queue has a relationship with patient.
     */
    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Patient','patient_id','id');
    }
}
```

This code block allows you to do some changes in database.

So you can get how many patients in the queue like this.

```
$queue= Queue::find(1);
foreach($queue as $item)
{
echo $item->patient;
}
```

If you want to get more information about relationships and models refer here :

[Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: this return more like an object within the object! Can't only one column be added to the Queue?

Comment: @szskdgi I dont think eloquent works like that.The relationship between models must be assigned as shown

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Queue::join('patient', 'queue.parent_id', '=', 'patient.id')
           ->join('shift', 'queue.shift_id', '=', 'shift.id')
           ->select('patient.name', 'shift.time', 'queue.date')
           ->get();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die();
```

here Queue is your model